# Angular 12 APP_INITIALIZER not firing before other modules

Tags: angular

I know this is an oft repeated question and I have read almost all of them for I have been trying to get an app_initializer to fire for many hours now but to no avail. So last resort is this

All I am trying to do is to load the rest end point of my spring boot app dynamically so that I can deploy to multiple environments.

My set up is something as follows:

AppConfigService

```
.....
loadConfig() : Promise<any> {
  const jsonFile = 'assets/config/config.json'; 
  return this.httpClient
      .get(jsonFile)
      .pipe(tap((result) =>{
        AppConfigService.settings = <IAppConfig>result;
        console.log(AppConfigService.getConfig());

      })).toPromise();

}
```

App Module

```
export function initializeConfigData(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    console.log("in app init fn");
    return appConfigService.loadConfig2();
  }
}
...
providers: [AppConfigService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeConfigData, deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true
  }]
```

What happens is that I have multiple modules in my app. For example the auth module has a service that makes an authenticate call to the rest end point and that seems to fire off even before the app initializer completes.

So right after I load the application I end up with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
```

on the console (root is the key in my config json data)

I have read multiple posts and I tried many things in my loadConfig method like trying to return a new Promise((resolve, reject) =>.... but nothing helped. Since I am on 12 I tried Observables too but nothing worked. Whatever I do my AuthenticationService fails stating that it cannot read that property.

What am I missing? Or is this is the behaviour when trying to get app_initializer to work when you have multiple modules.

Just to test things out I tried a simple setTimeout (no reading config for getting URL) and that fired as expected. So the damn thing fires but I think it is a question of timing..... I am at my wits end here, so any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share it on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload all my dependent code (like other modules) into stackblitz. Sorry but all relevant code as far as app_initializer goes is above. Anything specific you need?

Comment: App_initializer is not guaranteed to fire before other parts are booting. If you need guarantees, you could fetch your cofig in main.ts and pass it in as platform provider token.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the scenario above (using the provided code) and it seems like everything is working just fine (I don't have multiple modules, just the app module). I am logging the config inside `AppComponent.ngOnInit` and it always has the config value there. Nonetheless, I would like to propose another approach. Instead of writing and reading a static property on your `AppConfigService`, you could use an `Observable`. This way all the other things that depend on the config will wait until it's there.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppConfigService {
  private configSource = new ReplaySubject<IAppConfig>(1);
  // public static config: IAppConfig | null = null;

  public config$: Observable<IAppConfig> = this.configSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadConfig = (): Observable<any> => {
    const jsonFile = 'assets/config/config.json';
    return this.http.get(jsonFile).pipe(
      tap((result) => {
        // AppConfigService.config = result;
        this.configSource.next(result);
      })
    );
  };
}
```

AppModule looks almost identical with what you have (except I did not add `AppConfigService` in the providers array, as it's already `providedIn: 'root'`):

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeConfigData,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

And whenever you need to use your config, just inject the `AppConfigService` and do your http calls:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private appConfigService: AppConfigService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.appConfigService.config$.pipe(
      switchMap((config) => this.http.get(`${config.root.backendUrl}/users`))
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing it out for me. I think it is the modules that is causing the problem. In my case, the auth module which has to do an authenticate call against a REST end point immediately errors because it cannot get the end point URL from my config. However I will test your solution in my implementation and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Just one clarification. In the sample usage you have provided, that is not the only way of obtaining the config right? I mean I do not have to use switchMap for every http call that I need to make in each of my service right? Once injected in the constructor, I can store that value locally too, correct?

Comment: You can store the config value in a property, inside your `AppConfigService` as well. As I mentioned in the answer, this worked for me. The alternative that I proposed with observable config and switchMap is only here to help you overcome your issue, which I could not reproduce.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Duh, silly me - switchMap becomes mandatory because it guarantees that the config is available before the http call. But as @MikeOne has pointed out above, given that there are no guarantees with app_initializer with multiple modules (which is where my problem lies), your solution is more of a workaround right? I mean in the strictest sense, app_initializer should fire off before even the login auth call. I implemented the token solution via main.ts and that seems to guarantee that the config is available post which bootstrap happens. Just curious from a impl point of view